# What is the closed linear span of the Rademacher system in $L^2$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The question is in the title: *What is the closed linear span of the Rademacher system in* $L^2$?. The definition of the Rademacher system can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_system).

Comment: Questions should be in the body, not just the title.

Comment: Do those who downvote know the answer?

Comment: Assuming I'm correct in thinking that the right meta-answer is "A satisfactory answer simply does not exist": The close vote seems wrong. If he searched for the answer he wouldn't find it since it's not there. He can't show his thoughts so far because there simply isn't any such thing as a reasonable start towards answering the question. Etc. Otoh it's a reasonable question, and imo the existence of the question, with the answer "there is no answer" would be a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be good to specify $L^2([0,1])$.

I don't think that an answer of the sort you want really exists; I can't think of a true statement "$f$ is in the closed span of the Rademacher functions if and only if..." that's not just a tautology. (I say this in the hope that someone will prove me wrong.)

It might be interesting to note that set of Walsh functions, that is the set of all finite products of Rademacher functions (including the empty product $1$) is an orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,1])$. The Rademacher functions are a sparse subset of this basis, in a way very much analogous to the way the functions $\exp(2^n2\pi i t)$ form a sparse subset of the trigonometric basis.

Comment: $f \in L^2([0,1])$ is in the closed span of the Rademacher functions iff $\langle f, w\rangle = 0$ for every Walsh function $w$ that is not a Rademacher function.  Maybe not **quite** a tautology.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Maybe... I was certainly aware of this one when I said I doubted there was really a satisfactory answer; just says that $f$ is in this subspace if and only if it's orthogonal to the orthogonal complement.

Comment: It is a good point that the Rademacher family can be regarded as a subset of the Walsh basis. Let us wait for a few days, and if no new description appears, I will accept your answer. (I hope I can do it even if the question is closed.)